# Use admin-on-rest in my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, material-ui, admin-on-rest

i'm implementing an admin-tool site and i'm using material ui for this. I use redux saga for handling async calls (for calling services). The admin on rest has some very helpful components like the dataGrid. But for using them it is not as simple as i thought. 
Initially, for using this you should wrap you application inside the Admin component just like that:

```
const App = () => (
    <Admin restClient={simpleRestClient('http://path.to.my.api/')}>
        <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
    </Admin>
);
```

The restClient property as i understand from the docs is mandatory. I want to use the DataGrid component as i mentioned earlier, but when i tried to use it, an error is showing that resourse is undefined in a mapStateToPros function of the library. I must be missing something real important. But i find it very complex for just using an external Library. 
Is someone use this library before and provide me with some help. I just need to use the datagrids. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Admin-on-rest is not a UI library. It's an admin framework meant to be used as a whole. There are many React datagrids libraries out there. If you don't need a full Admin, don't use admin-on-rest

Answer (score 0):

If you just want Datagrid just use the Table component in Material UI.

Comment: Yes, but admin on rest supports material ui and the grid has so many functionalities that made it my first opinion

Comment: You can try and use AOR as a component in your custom app. https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you did not forget to import something from 'admin-on-rest'?

Your app should be declared something like that (some code missed):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { jsonServerRestClient, Admin, Resource } from 'admin-on-rest';

const restClient = jsonServerRestClient('http://localhost:8000')

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Admin restClient={restClient} >
                <Resource name="vendors" list={VendorList} />
            </Admin>
        );
    }
}
```

And VendorList should be declared something like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField } from 'admin-on-rest'

export const VendorList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="name" />
            <TextField source="description" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

In this example it will be get data from http://localhost:8000/vendors
I was never confronting with troubles in using admin-on-rest (maybe only when working with django-rest backend. But all was resolved.)